# How to use MIPS $k0 and $k1 registers

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu-registers

I was wondering, what are `$k0` and `$k1` registers in MIPS architecture.
As there is on [WikiBooks MIPS Assembly](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MIPS_Assembly/Register_File)

> The k registers are reserved for use by the OS kernel.

But I couldn't find anything about **what are they usefull for?** and also **how to use them?**

Thank you.

Comment: `$k0` and `$k1` are just aliases for registers `$26` and `$27` respectively. The "reserved" part is just by convention, the cpu doesn't care. The OS can use it for whatever it wants. Can be useful as scratch registers that can be used without fear of corrupting user space state.

Comment: @Jester OK, and so, How OS can use these registers? (Like `$1` which is used by assembler while is converting pseudo instructions, to instruction) (When I were looking for my answers, I faced terms like: "They are used for managing the interrupts" and so. How they are used in order of managing interrupts or what they are useful for?)

Comment: They are normal registers, you can use them as usual. Don't understand your question. As for managing interrupts, they can be used as scratch registers until the user state is saved. I said that already.

Comment: @Jester No, you _can't_ use them as scratch registers, period. From the perspective of user software, they should be presumed to be modified to random junk every clock cycle, for the simple reason that an interrupt could occur at any time; Including after you stored your temporaries to `k0` and `k1` but before you read it back, thus corrupting them. Ali's self-answer below is precisely to the point.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist scratch registers **in kernel**. Since the question was about how you can use it in kernel code. Since user software must not rely on the value that's precisely why you (the kernel) can modify them. And I have said that twice already.

Comment: @Jester Ah; I understood the question to be about user-space use of the registers. Nevertheless, even the OS can't so freely use it. On entry to an interrupt service routine, interrupts are masked. [At least in Linux,] the "top half" of the ISR then handles saving user state and doing work that must be done immediately and unpreemptibly. It then unmasks interrupts as soon as possible and does the "bottom half". During the bottom half's execution the system can be interrupted again, so you can only freely use them in the short top-half portion of ISR code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An interrupt handler must save any general - purpose registers that it is going to use (to be restored at return). But to do so requires you to modify at least one register first (something
like `sw $t0, saved_t0` expands to two machine instructions using `$at`).

This situation is resolved by forbidding user programs from using two general - purpose registers, `$k0` and `$k1` (The k stands for kernel, which an exception handler is part of). The interrupt handler is allowed to use `$k0` and `$k1` without having to save or restore their values. This allows just enough leeway to start saving registers, as well as making returning from the interrupt handler possible.